# Is there a way to UPDATE file metadata through dropbox api with Python?

Tags: python, cloud, metadata, dropbox, dropbox-api

I know you can get the metadata through dropbox API, but I would like to write metadata onto the files I have on dropbox, any ideas?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the standard metadata for files on Dropbox, e.g., `name`, `path_lower`, `client_modified` etc., as seen in [`FileMetadata`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/files.html#dropbox.files.FileMetadata), you do so by performing the relevant file operations. For instance, you can use [`files_upload`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload) to upload new/updated versions of files and set the `path` and `client_modified` when doing so, or you can move files (changing their path) by using [`files_move_v2`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_move_v2). (Some of the standard metadata properties though, e.g., `id`, are set by Dropbox and can't be arbitrarily modified.)

If you want to set custom metadata, i.e., something specific to your app, you can use [the "file properties" functionality](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/file_properties.html).

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful! However I was looking also at updating the file metadata and the above works for file-system metadata.